# TCP handshake reliability

Tags: tcp

I actually wanted to know, in a tcp handshake, why do client needs to ack back to complete the handshake.
Post syn and syn-ack, both parties have sufficient information to start the data, still tcp asks for client's ack to move to established state.

The question, is why this three way handshake is necessary and sufficient condition to achieve reliability, even tough we have sequence number synchronized post second message itself.

Any insights?

Answer (score 4):

How does the server know that the client received the SYN-ACK? The server has no way to know this unless the client explicitly sends an ACK to acknowledge that it got the syn-ack.

If this third ACK is dropped, the server will resend a SYN-ACK, and when the client gets that duplicate SYN-ACK, it'll say "oh hey, my previous ACK must have been dropped, so I'll just resend the ACK". This will continue until the server gets the AKC.

Comment: Correct, and server doesn't actaully needs to know correct? Why can't client simply start sending data without actually acknowledging the syn-ack.

Comment: Both the client and the server need to confirm that their connection is established. This is because both the client and server need to reserve some resources for the connection.

Comment: Client allocates resources at the time of sending syn, and server does that when it sends syn-ack, where's the third ack coming into picture here. See the question I have, is is the third ack really needed, my analysis suggests, post second message itself, both parties have all parameters synchronized, and if they want they can simply start sending traffic.. also if I am correct, the third ack, can't even be a piggyback to data. hope I have clarified the question well.

Comment: Imagine that the SYN-ACK got dropped. What would happen to those resources? In this case, the client might not be aware that the server agreed to the connection. This means that the server can't just send out a SYN-ACK and assume that the client will get it and everything will be fine. The server must wait until it gets an explicit confirmation from the client through that third ACK, and then it can safely finalize the connection. This third ACK ensures that both parties are aware of the connection.

Comment: See, SYN-ACk getting dropped is same as ACK getting dropped from Server's view, furthermore, SYN-ACK getting dropped actually doesn't actaully affects client, it will anyway retry.

Comment: @Varun: I think TCP stacks will send the third packet before the client application has a chance to supply any data, but if that packet were lost en route to the server and the application supplied data before the server requested a retransmission, I think the retransmission would include that data.

Comment: I think it is just a hangover from past; people trying to justify a decision using whatever means are available. A two message sequence can reliably establish connection; the sequence numbers and what not can be exchanged with two messages. All this talk of 'what if this is dropped' can be repeated ad infitum to any number of messages. Why stop at 3, why makes the 3d one so special and packet drops after 3rd are suddenly not critical.